# how to use ssh git correctly?

Tags: git, ssh

CentOS 7, Git 2.16.2

Building a website, call it "godaddy.com"
Create a user godaddy
mkdir /home/godaddy/httpdocs
git init
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead

In my local Windows pc, add this remote origin with private key, success.
But I found that if user "godaddy" use sftp, he can visit upper directories, like /etc/httpd, /etc/init.d...

I think user should be limited in his home directory.

Use selinux? If dont use selinux, other way?
Use http git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a property of your SSH or user permissions setup and has little to do with Git itself.

One way to tackle this without fiddling with user permissions is to change the command invoked when this user accesses the server via SSH. By default, the user has normal shell access (i.e. a regular shell is spawned). You can change this by specifying a custom shell command. You can set in the `authorized_keys` file, usually located at `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

[git-shell](https://gitirc.eu/git-shell.html) is a limited shell that you can use for this purpose.

If you want more fine-grained control, consider [Gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/). If this is too much of a hassle, consider a service such as GitHub.

Also note that you do not want to push to a non-bare repository (that is, a repository with a working tree). If you need to set up a deploy procedure, use at least a triangular setup where you push from your local computer to a bare repository somewhere, then have something fetching from that to deploy. For a simple use-case this is easily scripted. There are also services such as [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/) that can do similar things.